# In the Jim Starlin Thanos stories, why does Thanos lose?

Tags: marvel, comics, thanos

There is something that I always wondered about in regards to Thanos. Why does he "want" to be defeated? I enough that he is his own worst enemy. It is just that Thanos in the Starlin stories, he self-sabotages just when he is on the cusp of victory. IS there more to the situation than this?  Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Acting like they want to lose is a [classic trope](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WhyDontYouJustShootHim) of villains everywhere.

Comment: He's obsessed with Lady Death, right?  Wants to meet her up close and personal.

Comment: Also, he's mad, as in not sane.

Answer (score 6):

Thanos loses because he considers himself unworthy.

[image]

The above panel is from [Infinity Gauntlet #5](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/9290/infinity_gauntlet_1991_5).